How do `constexpr` "compile time pointers" work in C++?
Background
Pointers cannot be used as T* p value parameters to a template (which is specialized at compile time), because the memory address &obj of some object T obj is only known at run time.
Question
If that background is correct, than how can a pointer be used at compile time instead of this being ill-formated:
constexpr size_t length(const char* str)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while (str[n] != '\0')
    {
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}


//...

constexpr size_t length = length("Monkey types Hamlet!");

What memory is str actually pointing to at compile time?

your premise is false: https://godbolt.org/z/TKKov3x6z.

You can get a compile time pointer to an object with static storage duration.  Those are special objects and have a special place in memory that is globally scoped to the program that they get stored in.  The compiler knows how this happens so it knows how to get an address for where in the special memory the object will be located in.

@NathanOliver Besides global variables as in @ 463035818_is_not_an_ai s perfect example, what else has static storage duration? Apparently string literals?

anything globally scoped, anything at namespace scope, all string literals, and anything declared static has static storage duration.

string literals need to be static because there is no fundamental string type in C++.  A string is just an array of characters so in order to implement that they are stored in arrays, and literals get a static array so that they are available for the entire duration of the code execution.

constexpr T obj = /* something */;

this expression requires that something is a constant expression, there is no difference between a pointer and a value, so long as the pointer and the object pointed to are constant expressions, therefore the following code is valid https://godbolt.org/z/eaT77cvjP
constexpr int value = 5;
constexpr const int* ptr = &value;

constexpr int add_one_ptr(const int* value)
{
    return *value + 1;
}
constexpr int add_one_value(int val)
{
    return val + 1;
}

constexpr int value1 = add_one_value(value);
constexpr int value2 = add_one_ptr(ptr);
constexpr int value3 = add_one_ptr(&value);

in case of C string literals, they are implicitly constexpr const char*

How can the memory address &value be determined at compile time? Especially if the compiler determines that the constexpr int value can be optimized away? I guess the central difficulty for me to understand is how can the compiler have an address of a memory cell with value if the program is not already compiled, loaded in memory and then being executed?

@vohir you can just assume the compiler runs the code assuming this value is stored somewhere and that the pointer points to a valid location, it is not impossible to write a small interpreter to do this at compile time, the compiler could later optimize away variables that are not needed at runtime, as for how a constexpr address is computed, since this is a pointer to static data it can be computed at compile time, the linker will just change it later to the correct location in the data section of the binary, and the dynamic linker will also correct the pointer when loading the binary.

@vohir pointers to static data are simply stored as the offset from the start of the binary in memory, then when the binary is loaded into memory those pointers are incremented to point to where the data will actually be at runtime.

Let's assume the program includes a command cout << ptr << endl;. As ptr is constexpr this would always print the same number to the console.  Would that be the offset from start of the binary? What if value gets optimized away? Or does taking the address prevent optimizing away?

@vohir let's say the pointed-to data is stored at offset 500 from the start of the binary, the compiler simply stores 500 there, when the binary is loaded into memory, say at address 20,000, it also increments all pointers to static data by 20,000, so it will print 20,500 but the next time the binary is loaded it could be at 50,500 due to ASLR and it will print 50,500, the compiler doesn't care, it only sees it at 500, and can compute what 500 points to because constexpr evaluation happens at compile time, and doesn't care what offset will be added at runtime by the dynamic linker.

@vohir compilers really abuse the as-if rule, you don't need to map compile time behavior to runtime behavior, a simple interpreter is doing all the compile-time stuff, and at runtime when the cout << ptr << endl; is executed there will be a pointer that points to some static data that will be printed, as if you have no constexpr in the code.

@vohir according to the as-if rule, you can see the following code print the length of a string, but the string is optimized away https://godbolt.org/z/3rE1E1oe5 , and if you need a pointer to some static data then the compiler will store the data in the binary, and store a pointer to it that will be pointing to valid data at runtime.
